# How to import and run function script in my mail blade page

Tags: javascript, laravel

I'm trying to show the generated QR Code in mail. I tried using @stack and @push but nothing happens :(

```
@component('mail::message')
# Thank you for registering with us

Hello {{ $preregistration->firstname }}! kindly click the button below to get your QR code.

  <div id="qrcode"></div>
  <script src="js/qrcode.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      new QRCode(document.getElementById("qrcode"), "{{ $preregistration->qrcode }}");
    </script>

@component('mail::button', ['url' => url('/code/' . $preregistration->id)])
Download QR Code
@endcomponent

Thanks,<br>
{{ config('app.name') }}
@endcomponent
```